# Google Cloud Services, Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object, private URL access denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-denied, signed-url

I am using Google cloud storage to store images in a private folder, and I would like to display them in my website.
I followed this [documentation of Signed_URL in my own program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually) to achieve my goals.

After few tests, I can't display anything else than this image below.
[image: Access Denied]

I create a role for service account that contains the 'storage.objects.get' permissions, and I added this role to my service account. So, I do think that the URL that I generate doesn't  recognize my service account..

Any advice is welcome, thank you in advance,

Sincerely,

Théo.

Comment: Your service account must authenticate with a key.

Comment: My next step would be to get the signed URL the website is creating to make sure it's being generated correctly. Then I'd test that URL in a private browsing session (to avoid passing through my GCP auth). Have you already tried this?

Comment: Can you share how you generate the signed URL?